# Rails 3 AJAX remote form call backs

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading from rails 2.3.8 to 3.0.0, so I need to replace the `remote_form_for` helper calls with `form_for(@object, :remote=>true)`.

I've been following along with [Simone Carletti](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) but I cant seem to get the ajax callbacks from `rails.js` to fire.

My generated HTML is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/vendor_shipments" class="new_vendor_shipment" data-remote="true" id="formname" method="post">
```

The javascript I'm testing with:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
   alert('document ready');
   $("#formname")
      .bind('ajax:loading', function() {alert("loading!");})
      .bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {alert("success!");})
      .bind('ajax:failure', function(xhr, status, error) {alert("failure!");})
      .bind('ajax:complete', function() {alert("complete!");});
});
```

The 'document ready' alert fires, and the ajax request is successfully executed (data is posted to the server), but none of the '`ajax:____`' callbacks fire.

What am I doing wrong?

(for what it's worth, the form itself is loaded via ajax)

Comment: I think that the event is 'ajax:error' these days.

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2.11 and still callbacks are not working? any help or idea?

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz maybe my answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16759013/946328

Comment: @MaxSchmidt thanks for your reply. I solved this before and I was not including Jquery libirary files twice. Instead I included same file twice once manually and other was by application.js

Comment: As a heads up for posterity, the function signatures for the callbacks are incorrect. They should start with an event param first.  The docs are confusing.  I.e. bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wow, that was a colossal waste of an evening.

Doing it the way I did, the default prototype `rails.js` won't linkup the callbacks.

After converting to the jQuery based `rails.js` (http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)  callbacks are working fine.

Comment: Would be helpful if you linked or provided a sample of how to do it.

Comment: @jcollum, delete prototype-based rails.js from `public/javascripts/` and replace it with the jQuery based one

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the Prototype-based callbacks like so:

```
$('formname').observe('ajax:before', function(){
  ...
});

$('formname').observe('ajax:complete', function(request){
  ...
});
```

However, I don't think the `request` object in the `ajax:complete` callback contains the **response**.  I'm used to jQuery and had hoped that accessing the response would be simple.  Instead, it looks like switching to jQuery-Rails may still be easier, as I can't seem to find drop-in Prototype code to replace the `:update` functionality from Rails 2 remote helpers.

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer don't fixed your problem, check if you have embedded multiple jQuery libraries. In my case I had two different version of jQuery embedded and after removing one of them, everything worked fine.