# Rails 3 javascript form callbacks not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason my Rails 3 callbacks are not firing. Here is my form code:

```
<%= form_tag('/create', :method => "post", :remote => true ,:id => "create") do %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#create')
      .bind('ajax:loading', function() {alert("loading!");})
      .bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {alert("success!");})
      .bind('ajax:failure', function(xhr, status, error) {alert("failure!");})
      .bind('ajax:complete', function() {alert("complete!");});
});
</script>
```

The ajax post works perfectly and nothing else seems to be throwing any errors so I cannot  understand why **none** of the callbacks are functioning.

Any guesses?

Edit:

My rails.js seems fine. Here are my headers.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/main.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/respond.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Did you do this to make sure rails.js is in order? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723118/rails-3-ajax-remote-form-call-backs

Comment: Yes. I'm editing my post to include the current headers.

Comment: Have you tried putting `jquery_ujs.js` last in the loading order?

Comment: Yup, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Don't suppose you have this up somewhere we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the event parameter in your function as the first parameter.

`function(e, data, status, xhr) {alert("success!");})`