# rails 3 - ajax form ajax:success event not being called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

After much troubleshooting, I am not able to figure out why my form's ajax:success callback is not being called in rails 3.

**Following is the code ultimately generated in my view:**

**JS Code:**

```
$(function() {
  $("#myform").bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert("form success");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
  }).bind('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(status);
  });
});
```

**Ajax Form:**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/myc/mya" data-remote="true" id="myform" method="post">       <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="hZuhxwboQj2qo8MPIR8DWwYMqAC1V2yqG+DX9UnlIr0=" /></div>
          <input class="large" id="foo" name="foo" type="text" />
        <input class="btn success" data-disable-with="Working..." name="commit" type="submit" />
        </form>
```

**Following the logic that happens in the action which the form posts to:**

```
 @foo = { :foo => "bar" }
 render(:json => @foo.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json',
        :layout => false)
```

I have Firebugged this entire request/response:

```
It says 200 OK. And the Response Headers are:

Cache-Control   max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  13
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 23 Jan 2012 10:37:19 GMT
Etag    "9bb58f26192e4ba00f01e2e7b136bbd8"
Server  WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
Set-Cookie  _session_id=BAh7CkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlMGIzZGRhZDQ2ZjNmYzUzOWJkMzBkZWMxZDBmMDgwODZJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFoWnVoeHdib1FqMnFvOE1QSVI4RFd3WU1xQUMxVjJ5cUcrRFg5VW5sSXIwPQY7AEZJIhJyZXF1ZXN0X3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMGlCVmFZYllrU2R1RHl2aVZ4ZGc3ZWxKdmVxZkdFa1VKYWVXaHU0eXBmR1kGOwBUSSIZcmVxdWVzdF90b2tlbl9zZWNyZXQGOwBGSSIwcFdGTUVTUGt6d2VSY1pzV2YxU3JLNmFJSEpCU3FGMDh2ZmZ2U0pFaVI4cwY7AFRJIhRjdXJyZW50X3VzZXJfaWQGOwBGSSIpZDZiZDdhMjYtNDRjNi0xMWUxLTkwMDItZmExMjJjNjJmZTFmBjsARg%3D%3D--78099c697506ede3c7e9a833efa1785c6f1b9a6e; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime   0.354051
X-Ua-Compatible IE=Edge
```

The response is, as expected:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

200 OK response should trigger 'ajax:success' in my JS... but this is not happening. Any thoughts? The error callback is not being hit either...

Comment: Anything in the JS console? Is the missing paren in the JS a typo?

Comment: Nop, no errors in JS console.. fixed the paren just in case and still doesnt work. Also checked in the console if the 'ajax:success' event has bound to the form and it has.

Comment: Update the code in the question, then; it will their people off. There's no "just in case"; without it the JS is broken.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue.  After 90 minutes of searching I finally got it to work by using the following:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.delete', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1609186/ivan-fong

I was creating and then trying to delete what I had just created, all via ajax requests.  hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

After wasting a lot more time on this, I finally got it to work by doing the following:

1) Moving the 'ajax:success' binding to application.js rather than in the  tags in my partial.

2) Changing $(function() { }) to jQuery(function($) { })

Not exactly sure why the above two steps fix the issue, but they do. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, and your own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972522/946328) to your question also helped me. But I think this is only a workaround for the real problem. There are two possible situations when this problem appears:

1. You've upgraded from Rails 2 to 3 and still using the prototype library (see [Rails 3 AJAX remote form call backs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723118/rails-3-ajax-remote-form-call-backs))
2. You've embedded two jQuery Libraries (this was my problem)

So look in your html source code if there is another library that is in conflict with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It works on form id
like:

```
$("form#some_id").bind('ajax:success', function(){ ..... })
```