# Rails Ajax call on ajax uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm learning Rails and I understand how ajax call works. But I have a problem: I don't know how can I bind an ajax function on object loaded in the DOM with another ajax function.

In my demo page I use Plupload plugin to upload some files: when the script finish to upload the files I load, with ajax, the thumbnails in my preview window. Everything works fine.

```
        $("#multi_upload").pluploadQueue().bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'html',
            url: $('.wmk_grid#large_grid').data('gallery-url'),
            success: function(result) {
              $('.wmk_grid#large_grid').html(result);
            }
          });
        });
        $('.plupload_header').remove();
        }
```

Every thumbnail has also a "delete" button: on this button I attach a rails ajax call to delete the single picture.

My coffeescript is this:

```
$ ->
  $('.img_action_remove').bind 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
```

I know the issue: when I load my page I don't have any item with `.img_action_remove` class: i create them when I upload the pictures with plupload.

How can I fix the second ajax call?

*Update: fixed with this script:*

```
$(document).on "ajax:success", ".img_action_remove", (e) ->
  $(e.currentTarget).closest("li").remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JQuery Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> When I load my page I don't have any item with .img_action_remove
>   class: i create them when I upload the pictures with plupload

```
$('document').on 'ajax:success', '.img_action_remove', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
```

This binds the event to the document & delegates to the class. Means that you can create the class any time you want, and JS should always capture the event

Comment: @rickpeck Not working. Is there any way to debug this? I try to insert an "alert" but also the alert is not working. In my developer tools the state of ajax request is 200 OK, and the image is removed so the request is fine.

Comment: I think that my situation is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970346/rails-3-ajax-form-ajaxsuccess-event-not-being-called)

Comment: Hey Roberto, I was actually going to write another part to my answer - which is that I think there are some fixes which need to be applied to your process. I'll address them in an update for you :)

Comment: I fix it!!! But I want to know your solution... I solve with this [gist](https://gist.github.com/robypez/8113216)